# Does flatness imply components map dominantly?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I suspect the following is well-known, but I cannot find a reference.

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of complex algebraic schemes, which is *flat*. We can assume both $X$ and $Y$ are reduced. Is it true that every irreducible component of $X$ maps onto an irreducible component of $Y$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the map need not be onto, consider $k[x] \subseteq k[x,x^{-1}]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=X_1 \cup \cdots \cup X_r$ be the decomposition of $X$ in irreducible components. Now let $U_i = X_i - \bigcup_{j \neq i} X_j$ an open dense subset of $X_i$ and also irreducible. The map $U_i \to X \to Y$ is flat and therefore open. So $f(U_i)$ is open and irreducible in $Y$ and therefore an open subset of a certain irreducible component $Y_j \subseteq Y$. As such it is dense in $Y_j$ and the more is $f(X_i)$ dense in $Y_j$. So dominance is true, as you asked in the title, but "onto" is not necessarily true, as I showed in the comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have a nice day :)